# Throttling trusted users

Tags: discussion, answers, privileges, rate-limiting

I have >20k rep on stackoverflow.com. I was answering some questions today and evidently I was doing so too quickly. When I attempted to post an answer I got the message below.

[image]

Considering the fact that I'm a trusted user this seems un-necessary. It's not a big deal, but I thought I'd bring it to your attention in any case.

Comment: \*Proceeds to gain 20k rep to spam SO*

Comment: Oh my!  This is still better then asking one to enter a 42-digit prime number in order to post.

Comment: @devnull not really - they can just program the bot to come back after 60 seconds. But seriously, throttling trusted users is not good. It pisses people off because they/we like to be efficient, save time, have better things to do than to wait for a freaking timer to run out. CAPTCHA's are the worst thing invented by man, but atleast you can do it right away. (please don't enable captchas) - there must be another way...

Comment: I don't think I've ever hit this one before, and it seems as though you haven't either. [Comments, however...](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164048/please-make-the-multiple-comment-timer-less-annoying-non-resetting-etc).

Comment: Hmm.. on a serious note if one can _read_ and _write_ the answer to a question in less than 60 seconds then it'd usually signal a problem with either the question or the answer.  Chances would be that the question is a FAQ in which case it better be closed.  The answer is also likely to be a low-quality post unless a  [link-only answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/251514/how-should-accepted-link-only-answers-be-handled/) in which case it could be _improved_ by the readers.

Comment: Two of the answers you posted are identical, if you're copy-pasting answers it is not that suprising that you'll run into the rate-limiting that way.

Comment: I read [both](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11081381/templatizing-a-project-in-visual-studio/23235953#23235953) [questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5132723/visual-studio-project-templates/23235979) before starting to answer. The questions were very similar so I provided the same answer (copy/paste).

Comment: I don't really think an answer that can be written in 60 seconds including reading and understanding the question, could be considered _good_. Maybe consider answering some more difficult questions (that require at least some research), if you are so much skilled user of SO? IF the questions are so much similar that the answer is the same, why don't you flag them as duplicates?

Comment: @SayedIbrahimHashimi if you can provide the exactly same answer to two questions, why not simply flag one as a duplicate of the other?

Comment: They were both old and answered questions so I didn't see the need. In any case I went ahead and flagged http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5132723/visual-studio-project-templates/23235979

Comment: Consider also that someone (on poor connectivity) might write answers offline, then want to paste them in...

Comment: @DNA: If you mean they might write answers to multiple questions and then want to post all of them one by one, then yes, this behaviour would be in the way. But then, why not write an answer, post, write another one, post etc.?

Comment: Maybe you should be __suspended__ for copy/pasting answers first.

Comment: Wow the negativity here is really surprising. I'll think twice before posting from here on out

Comment: @devnull 103,582,180,924,623,748,121,674,293,193,717,277,486,911 May I please post now? I promise I'm not a robot!

Comment: @AdamDavis Sorry, a 125 digit prime number other than 12,277,777,777,777,777,777,777,777,777,777,777,777,777,777,777,777,777,777,777,777,777,777,777,777,777,777,777,777,777,777,777,777,777,777,777,777,777,777,777,777,777.

Comment: @devnull I suspect you are a robot.  Please supply a 124 digit prime number for verification.

Comment: @SayedIbrahimHashimi I have to admit though, I've stumbled across a number of questions in the review queues or that have a series of close votes - where I'd expect a *trusted* user to also be suggesting a close. Instead I've seen some of your answers on them. As @tereško said, it's not helping feeding the `help vampires`. Please think about the `community` rather than a bit of quick rep. If the community gets diluted by `help vampires` eventually people will leave, then your `rep` will be worth nothing in the grand scheme of things.

Comment: @ian i am thinking of the community that's why i posted the answers. It doesn't matter for my case since I'm not really answering questions here these days anyways

Answer (score 94):

Oh, but this seems really necessary.

Especially to combat users who are rep-farming. **You are not helping!** Instead you are lowering the quality of site and feeding [help vampires](http://slash7.com/2006/12/22/vampires/).

If the answer was so short, that it took you less than 1 minute, it should have been a comment and question should have been closed.

Comment: This is true. If you can answer a question in less than 60 seconds then theres a huge probability that the quality of the question and/or would be questionable. There might be a few instances where this might not apply but generally it does.

Comment: Just to be clear : is that the delay between 2 answers ?

Comment: In my experience, answers that took less than 1 minute are pretty common, and certainly not an expection... what you're suggesting is just silly. just because it takes less than a minute, it doesn't mean that there's anything wrong with the quality of the question. let me rephrase it: *if you're a seasoned developer and you cannot answer most of the questions of a beginner within a minute, there's probably something wrong with you*.

Comment: @Karoly Horvath: While I could *respond* to beginner questions under a minute, making the response into something that I'd consider a SO-worthy *answer* takes some time. I prefer posting an answer that is more nuanced than "use jQuery;" I don't really care if I'm two minutes late to the party, this is not a race. (That said, I don't have any problem with answers which start out short and are gradually filled in)

Comment: @KarolyHorvath: but finding the duplicate usually takes longer than 60 seconds, and is the right thing to do in most situations.

Comment: I partially agree with the author of this answer. One exception is when a **valid question is answerable in under a minute**. We are now talking about 2 like those in a row...(*very questionable..*). This *exception* should not apply to all the questions/answers so an occasional *`!Stop before you answer`* shouldn't cause any throttling

Comment: It seems to be quite common in order to mitigate the "fastest gun in the west problem" (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731) to post relatively short answers that likely get the OP forward, and then elaborate it into a better one afterwards. This might conflict with the 60s limit for some fast typers...

Comment: This calls for a `help-vampire` tag.   Or a badge.

Comment: Giving good answers is always a good thing, the motivation of the answerer doesn't matter.  In fact, you're just assuming this answerer's motivation. If it's an answer, it shouldn't be a comment.

Answer (score -9):

It is unnecessary.  Answers shouldn't be judged on how quickly someone was able to create it.  **The only thing that matters is whether it is a good answer or not**, and that is what voting is all about.

Comment: Lance, spammers post answers too and while we do have systems in place that very effectively mitigate them, the rate limiting is part of it. If it weren't that, it would probably just be increased captcha, which I think would annoy people even more. Consider the non-humans also, because that's _primarily_ what this curtails, along with trolling sprees / etc. [Remember this?](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/wp-content/uploads/stack-overflow-malicious-user.png)

Comment: @TimPost, yes, but we're talking about trusted users here.

Comment: @TimPost The link is dead