# Content oriented Captchas for suspected duplicates

Tags: discussion, feature-request, captcha

When I ask a question I get this element of "Questions that may already have your answer" above the question body. To me thats encuraging to look there for the answers, but it seems like not everybody reads them and thus duplicates get asked.

If the list is sorted by relevance (which I think it is) then how about this:

If the chance of this question beeing a duplicate is high enough (to be defined),
after posting the question the asker would have to solve a captcha based on the content of one of the questions.

It could require the asker to "Enter the second last word of the first answer of this question" or something the like and would force the asker to look at the answer. Maybe there is even an extra step asking the OP if the referenced answer already helped.

Wheather or not this should apply to high rep users is to be discussed.

A clarification from the comments: **Why would that improve anything, theese users are already ignoring the suggested answers anyway?**

The problem is that they don't **have to** interact with the suggested questions. There is no penality of just ignoring it. When I look on a regular online newspaper site there are links everywhere and they are 99% ads, so by now I just ignore all links that see, even the ones IN texts I read (except for SO and two other sites) - to the point that I'm about to write a css for me that just removes them from my vison. That of course changes when I HAVE TO read the content to solve the captcha.

**Yes this is annoying**, but thats not bad. If you REALLY want to post your question spending time on it is fine.

Background info:
I took the idea to use captachs as improvements for user generated content here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZG4FawUtYPA (German, "Trolldrossel").

In the linked youtube video the Operator had problems with Trolls (I'm not saying our users are trolls) on his comments page and solved his problem by measuring the likelyness of trolling in a given comment through keywords and then let the users fail the regular captcha with according chance. So if a comment was 50% likely to be trolling, the captcha would fail automatically with 50% chance.

The dup-posters are not trolls, but the same solution could help: If they really want to post their question, they should be able to do so; but only after a hard nudge to READ a different answer on this very topic.

Comment: What makes you think that these people will then actually read the question, instead of just doing mechanically what is asked for in the captcha?

Comment: @PlasmaHH Hope. If someone looks for something with topic X and sees keywords for it, he is probably interested in actually reading what its about. - of course I don't know for certain that this will help, but I think its worth a try. And I think its easy enough to implement to justify the try.

Comment: Sorry, that made me laugh. Maybe I am [too negative as of late](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251758/why-is-stack-overflow-so-negative-of-late) but don't you think that if that is the reason, they would have looked at the suggested/related questions that pop up while writing theirs too?

Comment: @PlasmaHH No, why should they, they have nothing to interact there with. My personal way of viewing the internet (except SO) is to agressivlely ignore anything that is not certain content because of all the advertising. I expect others to do the same, this measure would circumvent that. Also, laughing is good - if that cheers you up you might get more positive in the future and (so I hope) continue your stay here.

Comment: @PlasmaHH Also I wrote this suggestion because of the talks on the linked question, to make things better again and have this site the way I got to know it.

Comment: I am not saying this should not be done. I am just not seeing how it would help. It would be nice for everyone if it proves otherwise! You say they have nothing to interact there with. What exactly do you mean by that? When you are writing a question there are lots of (constantly changing) links around; pretty interactive I would say. If they are interested in topic X and see a link, is this really less likely to be looked at as the q/a text? If you say its just perception of keywords, maybe showing excerpts of the linked to questions is much less annoying than captchas?

Comment: I guess [this guy](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251744) would disagree with you. Maybe we should leave that feature out for high rep users? otoh for low rep users, if that interaction is too much they would probably just not post the question at all, maybe thats a good thing too...