# You can only post every 3 minutes?

Tags: discussion, support, answers, rate-limiting

Really annoying. I've been on SO for a while and I want to answer multiple questions related to technology I know about. I've proven not to be a spammer, but still I get the message that I can't answer a question more than every 3 minutes.

I just move away from SO then, because this is just annoying?

Comment: I doubt you can write two _good_ answers to two questions _worth answering_ in three minutes. But if that limitation annoys you too much, you're free to "move away".

Comment: No, it's about writing ONE good answer in 3 minutes.

Comment: @Boland: I am a pretty prolific answerer, but I never run into this limitation.. Really, it takes more than 3 minutes to write a good answer.

Comment: I don't think that's a duplicate @gnat. The OP has 85 rep, hardly a "trusted user".

Comment: @Yannis this only impacts throttling rate - 3 minutes vs 1; reasoning in the [answer there](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251755/839601) explaining the limitation applies here

Comment: Are you trying to copy/paste one answer to many related questions? That's not encouraged here. That's the only way I can see this limitation being a problem for someone.

Comment: I don't think there's a reason to assume malice here @eddie_cat. Especially since there's no trace of copy/paste answers in the OP's profile.

Comment: @Yannis didn't assume anything, if this is not the case that's great. But when I hear someone say they are consistently hitting a wall for trying to post answers in less than three minutes, it wouldn't *surprise* me if they were copy/pasting. It takes more than three minutes to even find another question worth answering most of the time... I could see hitting it once or twice, but not enough times to complain on Meta about it unless something was off.

Comment: This is not a dupe, the other is about "trusted users".

Comment: 3 minutes isn't much. Even if you manage to write a good answer in less than 3 minutes (which I doubt is possible), I don't see why it would be a problem to wait a minute or so before submitting.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I run into this as well every so often - but it's rare enough that it's not a problem. *Sometimes* it's possible to find another question to answer *and* write a good answer in under 3 minutes, but it doesn't happen very often - to me, at least.

My approach is just to leave the post ready to submit, go off and do something else, then submit it when the time limit has elapsed.

I'd rather have this limitation in place and it occasionally raise a false positive than not have the limit in place at all.

Comment: Thanks, this is a valid, nice answer, instead of questioning my capabilities and downvoting my answers!

Comment: Agreed, in my case i recently wrote up an extension answer in one thread but then wanted to post a link to it on another related thread as it took me 5 or 6 searches to find an answer to my particular problem.

Answer (score 19):

If you take less than 3 minutes on an answer a question and are in a position to post an answer to another question... well... that suggests that you are not posting high quality answers tailored to the questions.

That the system is stopping you from doing so is a good thing.

Comment: Alright, if that's your opinion. I'll spend my valuable time somewhere else and leave those questions unanswered. Some of the questions related to my knowledge can be answered within 1-2 minutes. Just trying to help...

Comment: @Boland - we never claimed SO was a place for everyone. We try to [optimize for pearls](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/06/optimizing-for-pearls-not-sand/), you see?

Comment: SO was a place for everyone when it launched. That is different now, I think it's fair enough.

Comment: I was around during the beta - it was never a place where everything goes. Low quality answers were getting downvoted on day one.

Comment: @Boland; if you truly have valuable knowledge to share that no one else can, then just wait the extra minute. The question will *still be there to be answered*.

Comment: You're making assumptions about the user's capabilities.  As Jon points out on his answer, it happens to him.  Do you think his answers are not high quality.  Throttling good answers can never be a good thing.

Comment: Ah, suddenly some of my old posts and recent answers get randomly downvoted. Thanks guys! What the...