# Why are there no badges for actually answering many questions?

Tags: discussion, answers

All the badges seem to be around answering in different kinds of scenarios (first, old, answer your own question etc).  None of them are related to something like "answering 100 questions".  Not sure if they need to be accepted answers, but wouldn't it be valuable to have people contribute their answers to increase community (eg. per question)?

Comment: related: [Throttling trusted users](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251755/839601)

Comment: Why does down voting even exist here, this is a meta group.

Comment: Voting is different on Meta. Often, it is used to show agreement/disagreement with a post. People likely disagree with your idea that we need these badges.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta

Comment: The downvoting probably means "There shouldn't be badges like this", possibly for the reasons listed by Meagar.

Comment: @kendra it looks like "users to communicate with each other" to me.  I did a bit of research in my question, and it's clear what I'm asking.  Yet it screams "don't ask this, you dolt".  Then it makes me consider removing my question, which prevents others from understanding the reasoning from meagar, defeating the purpose of asking in the first place.

Comment: You couldn't delete it anyway- The question has an upvoted answer. But if you check the link gnat posted, you'll see in the "Voting is different on Meta" section what I mean. Note that users _do not_ stick to the "only on feature-request" part of that- Most users vote for agreement/disagreement with the premise of a post regardless of the tag. People don't agree we need these badges. Your question is fine, Meta is just a much different beast than main SO is.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

We don't want to encourage volume, we want to encourage quality.

Most of the badges related to reputation already *do* encourage posting lots of **good** answers, so we hardly need badges which are solely about volume.

Comment: okay, but what about "answering 100 questions that are accepted"?

Comment: @ergonaut Having an answer accepted isn't hard, or badge-worthy, and we don't need to further incentivize "please accept my answer" spam comments.

Comment: This ignores the existence of tag badges, which do sort of encourage volume (with a minimum quality requirement).

Comment: @AnthonyGrist Almost all users hit the question objective before the score objective, so that's only a problem when a user's early question in a tag ends up on a viral question that gets a massive score.  That just happens so rarely that the cases of potential abuse are so small that it just isn't realized into *actual* abuse.  If the required questions for a tag badge were proportionally higher than the required score, then that could change.

Comment: @ergonaut the reward for answering 100 questions that get accepted is 1500 reputation points. A high volume of good answers will generate points, arguably no further encouragement is needed

Comment: @Servy Not sure why I worded that the way I did. I think my point was more "Badges for answering a lot of questions already exist in the form of tag badges."