# Gold Badge holders closing questions as duplicate to own answer for SEO?

Tags: discussion

I came across [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359059) earlier today, regarding Gold Badge abuse which reminded me of similar situations I've been experiencing with the [reactjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reactjs) questions. So I thought I'd post my own observation as well.

---

Many posts are being closed as duplicates by Gold Badge users to other posts they have answered themselves, even when there are posts out there that are much much more popular (i.e: up-votes / view count / number of answers posted).

Worth noting here is that their own answer is a duplicate to the popular question from the get-go, however they still chose to redirect all dupes to their own (duplicate) post.

Posts that are only partially a duplicate are no exempt. They too get frequently shut down within minutes, even though maybe 50% or more of the question remains unresolved from the referenced duplicate.

I can only assume that this kind of elaborate effort for SEO to their answers since search-engines index all questions on Stack Overflow. The more a given question is cross-referenced from another question, the more likely it is to appear higher up in search results. Having your answer be the top result on Google means more upvotes in the long run.

A wild, but reasonable I think, presumption of what's going on.

---

I don't mind Gold Badge users closing duplicate posts to an old answer they posted themselves, as long as that answer is the most helpful/useful - or at least comparable/debatable with other posts.

As seen in [this meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10841/how-should-duplicate-questions-be-handled):

> The general rule is to **keep the question with the best collection of answers**, and close the other one as a duplicate.

But this rule is clearly abused by certain Gold badge users. I am not sure if this is a common occurrence for other tags as well, but this is getting quite annoying.

Opinions?

**Edit** - The linked duplicate is invalid. This is not about posting an answer and then closing the post. This is about closing a post and always choosing the referenced duplicate be one where you have an answer in order to boost reputation. People seem to disagree, and that's fine, but let's at least lift this invalid dupe closure.

Comment: If you see a pattern, flag it. I haven't seen this yet, myself, but I can imagine someone being tempted to do so.

Comment: Eh, i do this sometimes, but it's because I know that I answered it and can easily find that one compared to others. Obviously if it's a dupe of some super canonical that'd be a case where they're trying to direct traffic, but... how much impact could that really have? I wouldn't assume malice in this case.

Comment: We need to stop focusing on users here on meta. We deal with content, mods deal with users. If you have a problem with a user, flag it. If you are uncertain about content, ask on meta.

Comment: @gnat, that post doesn't seem relevant. That is about answering a post and then closing it. This topic is about closing other posts and always linking those to other posts where you have an answer.

Comment: Right, but the same principal applies. What are we going to do to prevent this scenario that wouldn't also prevent or harm cases where there are legitimate reasons to close a question as a dupe of your own? If we're not going to implement some feature to deal with this, then we already have a solution; raise a flag.

Comment: It's not abusive to vote to close a question as a duplicate of a question that is in fact a duplicate and has a quality answer that answers the question being closed.  If you feel there is a better duplicate target out there that you think adds value on top of the existing duplicate target, then by all means, add it to the list of duplicates (or add it as a comment) but someone closing questions as a duplicate that are actually good duplicate targets is in no way abusive.

Comment: @KevinB, not sure. I didn't tag this as a feature-request because I don't have any tangible solutions to propose. Just an observation that I want to discuss.

Comment: The only question is : Valid dupe close or not? Everything else is not relevant.

Comment: whether or not it's a valid dupe close shouldn't include who posted the answer/question. I thought we were talking about whether or not it was abuse to do so.

Comment: @Chris: The fact of the matter is, it is *far easier* to find questions you yourself asked/answered than other questions. This is due to the site's crappy search function. If I asked the question and remember some key words from the title, then it takes me only 5 seconds to find it. That makes it much easier to find dupe-targets that I was involved in than those I wasn't.

Comment: @NicolBolas, I agree with that. However, you start noticing a pattern when many questions that are only partially a duplicate are closed leaving a major part of the question unanswered.

Comment: That sounds like a different problem. One that we have the tools to deal with on our own through reopening, or editing the dupe list.

Comment: @KevinB, there might indeed not be a solution to this because it's all about perception and a case-to-case thing. But the fact the possibility to do so is there is troubling in my opinion. Sometimes long posts that would take a normal person 2-3 minutes to read are closed within seconds because the title included a key-phrase that "sounds like [duplicate]"

Comment: @Chris: "*But the fact the possibility to do so is there is troubling in my opinion.*" I disagree. On some level, we *have to* trust people to behave reasonably. We have mechanisms in place to deal with the rare users who are acting maliciously: moderators. We don't need specific rules or tools in place to deal with such rare occurrences. The fact that abuse is *possible* should not be considered "troubling". It only becomes troubling if it happens with significant regularity.

Comment: @NicolBolas, hmm fair point I guess. Like I said though, I don't believe that any mechanism fixes this, since it's a matter of perception. I guess flag and move on is what applies here.

Comment: @Chris If you feel that someone is marking a question as a duplicate when it's not in fact a duplicate, then that's a radically different situation than them marking a question as a duplicate when it's actually a duplicate.  In neither case is whether they have an answer on the target relevant to resolving the problem.

Comment: @NicolBolas *"The fact that abuse is possible should not be considered "troubling". It only becomes troubling if it happens with significant regularity"* Agreed, and it does happen quite frequently with [tag:reactjs] questions. Apparently not with other tags, and that's one of the things I didn't know - I usually only answer questions with that tag. Hence why I posted.

Comment: What i've seen done occasionally is one dupe target replaced with another when someone assumes malice on dupe closure. Personally, I think it'd be better to leave both in place if they both answer the question. If you think there's some pattern, that's for mods to deal with. Us dealing with it is more likely to cause problems.

Comment: Since we are talking about abusing goldhammer I just did that and abused my goldhammer  to re-open this question as I agree that this one is different. Let's discuss that now :)... And to not increase abuse my answer is in comment... which is against the rules... which is abuse again... dropping hammer on the floor.

Comment: I see no problems with such closing and I don't believe there "SEO juice" to questions in the middle of duplicate chains... (you may want to make separate question on SEO impact if we don't have one yet).

Comment: So if someone asked/answered the canonical dupe target for a question they shouldn't be able to chose it as a target when using the dupe hammer?

Comment: @JoeW this isnt a feature request to block people from doing that though. This is a question to discuss situations where a) the choice of dupe target doesnt seem to be the MOST appropriate one, and b) the dupe target has an answer from the dupe-closer, which can indeed look like abuse.

Comment: @Patrice Exactly. I am also not referring to the behavior where this can happen on occasion (I've done that myself sometimes). I am talking about what seems to me like an obvious pattern with intent.

Comment: @Chris To be clear, "their own answer is a duplicate to the popular question from the get-go" means the duplicate target (non-canonical Q&A answered by the gold-badge-holder) has already been closed as a duplicate of the canonical one, correct? The ambiguity of "is a duplicate" is tripping me up here -- the gold-badger's question could be a duplicate of the canonical without being correctly *marked* as a duplicate. (Sorry for the nitpick, but the difference would change my read on the situation slightly.)

Comment: @apsillers I don't blame you. I meant that the dupe target is either a duplicate of another post or should be (aka the dupe target shouldnt have been posted to begin with)

Comment: @apsillers For example, imagine somebody posts *"How to print to console"* in javascript, instead of closing it as an obvious dupe, you go ahead and answer it. Next time that same question is asked you put that answer of yours as the dupe target. Both actions seem fishy. Especially when this is a repeated occurrence

Comment: @Patrice I think you are misunderstanding, just because a question is closed as a duplicate of a canonical question doesn't mean that there are other canonical questions it could be a dupe of. The point is that it is possible for a question to be a duplicate of multiple questions and people tend to pick the ones they can find the fastest.

Comment: @JoeW the problem id that the general rule (se quoted text in my question) is in this scenario **never** applied.

Comment: I mean, sure, i guess it's said general rule isn't being perfectly followed, if you assume every user knows about or is able to find every possible question that exists on the network to be able to choose "the *best* one" but... that's simply not the case. and best is subjective anyway.

Comment: The whole point of giving gold badge holders dupehammer privileges is precisely because they are familiar with the tag and can recognize duplicates very quickly.  The fact that they themselves have answered this duplicate is to be expected because a gold badge requires 200 answers for the tag.  Besides, the catalog of _your_ answers is a very accessible list via your profile.  So unless you think someone is being egregiously inaccurate in the dupe closing, it's not really a problem.