# Please let every member see vote counts on meta, regardless of reputation

Tags: feature-request, meta

Could you make [viewing vote counts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/established-user) (total upvotes and total downvotes) for every post on Meta viewable for every Stack Overflow member regardless of reputation, please? We all have no time to write an answer or a comment for every post we have opinion about. For example, I agree with some comment or answer, so I vote at the post and at that comment. And the author needs the statistics on such users' opinions for his/her post.

I think, that will make it easier for him/her to see what propositions attract more interest and what is the sign of that interest.

Practically, **we are voting** for every post on Meta. And what is the sense of voting if we can't see the true results? And that voting is much more important on Meta Stack Overflow than on Stack Overflow itself.

At a minimum, let the person who asks a question see these totals on their question and on all answers to their question. And for the author of an answer to see that for his/her own post.

+10-10 for a feature means that many people need that feature. And simultaneously, many people consider it inconvenient. So, the author needs to think how to make it not so inconvenient for these who are against it now. The post needs very careful edition. +0-0 means that nobody is interested in the feature. Or it is written in a language that nobody understands. The same about answers that propose changes for the feature.

If I want to comment or answer to a feature request that has +0-0, I very probably will decide not to waste my time on a message that won't be read anyway.

On the contrary, if a post has +10-10, then very probably, my message will be read and I won't waste my time invested into it.

Comment: It looks like you propose this to resolve a specific issue but I find it difficult to understand where an when users have a problem when they can't see what propositions attract more interest. What solves your feature request?

Comment: [seems about time for that...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dJ7F4.png)

Comment: @rene When I am putting a post on Meta, the reason of existence of the question and answers is to know what people think about the question. And about the answers, too. The rights to see +-votes start about at rep 1500, I am not sure. Thus, absolute majority of Meta cannot use the very important Meta feature, one of the reasons of its existence. Sorry, I cannot explain it better with my English.

Comment: May I try to find an alternative wording then? If I understand it right, you want all Meta users to be able to see the upvote and downvote totals. So that every Meta user can see both the upvotes and the downvotes on a post. Which should help them judge how unanimous/contested a post is.

Comment: That is exactly what I understood as well. And I quiete like it. Although performance could become an issue as indicated by @Pekka웃. Perhaps some form of caching could do the trick here? Or a certain threshold after which it would become visible. Like only enable it after 50 votes.

Comment: My comment was in response to someone else worrying about performance. I don't think there is a performance problem activating this on Meta sites, where there are very page views compared to the main sites. But then I'm not a SO engineer so I don't know for sure.

Comment: @S.L.Barth Exactly. And, as you see, I have to explain why I want it and what problem of users will be solved by it. It is here that the misunderstanding appeared.

Comment: What problem would this solve? Would you vote differently if you could see how other people voted? Why?

Comment: Have I **inspired** this, [somehow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/360033/4577762)?

Comment: @CodeCaster No, but someone that has -5 and +4 will THINK that one person disagree, end of story. But the reality is : 5 persons disagree, and 4 agree. which makes a humongous difference to me. This is a valid request.

Comment: @AntoinePelletier:  The number of people that agree...really doesn't factor into much.  This isn't a voting democracy, this is a consensus-based system.  A largely positive score indicates some form of consensus.  Usually, the highly contentious posts with mixed score will offer some kind of discussion to justify positions, which will *also* be scored depending on the same factors as the question.

Comment: @Antoine _"This is a valid request"_ - I'm not discussing the validity of this request, I'm asking for motivation. _"makes a humongous difference to me"_ doesn't really do a lot to convince me, as it doesn't explain _why_.

Comment: Yes it makes sens the way you see it, it was just my opinion

Comment: If i base it on fact instead, i'de say @FirstOne comment actually answer this question : It's no use to see votes while they are building up, the final score tells you what you need to see.

Comment: Related on MSE: [Please reduce or eliminate the reputation required to see the upvote/downvote vote split](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72743/please-reduce-or-eliminate-the-reputation-required-to-see-the-upvote-downvote-vo). The limitation only exists at a UI level on the website, at this point.

Comment: @FirstOne Without any doubt, I thought about using Achevement list as the source of information on numbers, but than I thought - why to stop on the half of the way. We need these number on Meta - let us see them on Meta. So, all people pointing at problems about my previous question helped this one to appear.

Comment: @Makoto Yes. And that is one of the reasons why I think we all need to see both numbers on Meta, and not only up-down.

Comment: If memory serves, the reason for making this a privilege at all was that it's expensive (since the individual counts aren't denormalized). So making it available to *everyone* is probably asking for a DoS. But lowering the threshold might be possible, though I'm not convinced it would actually accomplish what you think it would.

Comment: @Shog9 - couldn't it only be available to signed in users and requests be rate limited per account?

Comment: @MartinSmith Surely, I mean only participants of Meta. And sorry, what do you mean by "rate limited per account"?

Comment: @Gangnus - Shog's comment above indicated that the only way of preventing a DoS would be to restrict the capability by reputation. But this isn't the only way. Restricting the number of attempts each account can make in a certain period is used for other site functionality.

Comment: I agree with OP. For context, [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359124/gold-badge-holders-closing-questions-as-duplicate-to-own-answer-for-seo) is one of my own questions. It has a score of 2, making it look like 2 people agreed - in reality 13 up-voted while 11 down-voted, which effectively makes it a rather controversial topic that it seems.

Comment: @AntoinePelletier No, that doesn't make any difference. Still, if You have -1 that means **majority disagrees**. Having  -5/+4  or -3000/+2000  makes no difference. 
Besides, allowing people to see voting results before the actual vote **will always make them biased**.  That's why You don't see something like official *live* score during the election in real life...

Comment: I'm struggling to see any benefit in this at all. Current vote count shouldn't affect how you vote anyway, so the totals only really matter to whoever is basing a decision on these numbers. However, I would support vote counts on posts where the reader is also the asker. Perhaps even if they have answered too.

Comment: @Skipper About politics - recall the two-round elections in many countries. So, your "You don't see something like" - is simply false. But the comparison is bad anyway, for there we mostly have many variants and here - two only. "Current vote count shouldn't affect how you vote anyway," - agreed. But it can influence the appearance of new answers and edits to answers and the question.

Comment: @Skipper +100-100 for a feature means that many people need that feature. So, the author needs to think how to make it neutral for these who are against it now. +0-0 means that nobody is interested in the feature. Or it is written in the language that nobody understands. Great difference.

Comment: @Skipper Notice, we are not discussing if +10-10 and -0+0 make no difference or not (moderators and developers see this info anyway), but if it makes the difference to the author and other readers/writers.

Comment: @Shog9 I think that reason no longer applies. The current vote count is already a cached sum of all the votes cast. It should be possible to extend that cache to include separate sums for up/down votes. But it's probably being kept this way for historical reasons or perhaps the current implementation might be so deeply ingrained into the code-base that it's difficult to make such a change without breaking a lot of other things.

Comment: Not exactly a cache, @Mysticial; score is a permanent field on Posts. It gets recalculated when there's a vote (but not necessarily correctly) and via nightly activity that attempts to correct any discrepancies that arose from race conditions while voting, and also whenever someone retrieves the vote split. But normally (heh...) it's used as-is; crucially, the vast, vast majority of page renders don't require hitting the votes table at all. Could this be changed? Yes; is it worth the investment? Eh...

Answer (score 29):

While it isn't a full answer to the problem, there is [“View Vote totals” without 1000 rep](https://stackapps.com/questions/3082/view-vote-totals-without-1000-rep) (available as a [userscript](https://greasyfork.org/en/scripts/6192-stack-exchange-view-vote-totals-without-1000-rep), a [Google Chrome Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/view-vote-totals-without/oibfliilcglieepgkdkahpfiiigdijdd?hl=en), or [bookmarklet](https://userscripts-mirror.org/scripts/show/125051)), which provides anybody the ability to view vote counts on all Stack Exchange sites, whether logged in or not and whether over or under 1000 reputation.<sup>*</sup>

<sub>*No affiliation, just an extension I find useful.</sub>

Comment: https://stackapps.com/questions/3082/view-vote-totals-without-1000-rep