# Why did I get Mortarboard for Meta votes?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, badges, meta, daily-reputation-badges

[A question of mine](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/360088/please-let-everybody-see-vote-counts-on-meta-regardless-of-reputation), being published on Meta, had got many upvotes. More that 40/day. And at the end of that day I had got a Mortarboard badge. Of course, I would be proud to get that very difficult badge, but honestly.

[The definition of Mortarboard](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/41/mortarboard)  says: ***Earn at least 200 reputation (the daily maximum) in a single day.*** BTW, you'll see there many others false mortarboarders, such as me.

But for Meta we are getting no reputation. I had NOT got 200 reputation. If we should be honoured for many positive votes for our posts on Meta, the budge should be formulated another way. Or even do more of them - for 40 pluses, 100 pluses, 300 pluses or such. But the definition of Mortarboard should be changed on Meta.

And how these votes are counted now? As we have no reputation additions, questions and answers here on Meta have no difference in evaluation. (I think, it is fair, here questions should not cost less) But how was this "MetaMortarboard" counted?

So, the current definition of MetaMortarboard  lies twice. And very probably the badge is not counted in a sensible way.